# Labeling points on a plane

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, scoping

I have two points in a plane, both depending on several parameters. The coordinates of them shall fall within the range [0,1], i.e. within the red square:

[image]

I would like to draw these points for many values of the parameters, labelling them according to these values in order to show which of them fall within the red square and which not.

Here my code for the background and the red square.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=-2,ymax=2, samples=1000, xlabel={$c$},
ylabel={$s$},unbounded coords=discard]
\draw[red,thick,dashed] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There undoubtedly are more elegant ways [image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{try.csv}
0.5  0.5
0.25 0.75
1.5 -1
-1 -1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=-2,ymax=2]
\draw[red,thick,dashed] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:1,1);
\begin{scope}
\addplot[only marks,blue,clip mode=individual] table {try.csv};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:1,1);
\addplot[only marks,clip mode=individual,red] table {try.csv};
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to add a label?

Comment: To each point or just one for the.blue points and one for the red?

Comment: To each point, or by checking the points with different colours (green, blue, black, orange etc)

Comment: @Mark I guess you should provide the data, i.e. the colors, first, then one can add the labels with `nodes near coords`.

Comment: I agree with @marmot